# My link <a> tag isn't responding to my CSS orders

Tags: css

I am trying to get the "start a new post" to respond because i plan on using jquery to show/hide a form.  is this the best way? the "start a new post" isn't responding to any styling that i am doing in CSS.

here is my HTML code

```
<div id="start_new_post">
<a class="non_link" href="" alt="start a new post">Start A New Post</a>
</div>
```

here is my CSS

```
#start_new_post {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #C00;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left: 50px;

}
.non_link a:link {
    color: #C00;        
}
.non_link a:visited {
    color: #C00;    
}
.non_link a:hover {
    color: #C00;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

am i trying to access it wrong with the CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `a` tag with the `class` `non_link`, not all `a` tags under an element `class` `non_link`.
Do it like that:

```
a.non_link:link {
    color: #C00;        
}
a.non_link:visited {
    color: #C00;    
}
a.non_link:hover {
    color: #C00;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.non_link:hover` is what you want.

`.non_link a:hover` selects an `a` that is the child of `.non_link`.